# is this sentence grammatically/structure correct?

Tags: sentence-structure

```
lass deine Zunge an die Deutsch Sprache gewöhnen
```

(context is that let you Tonge get used to the German language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this sentence is not correct as Janka outlined in her answer.

However, you could say

> Lass deine Zunge sich an die deutsche Sprache gewöhnen.

Answer (score 4):

No.

- Sentences start with a capital letter and end with a full stop.
- The word *deutsch* is this case is an adjective and has to start with a small *d*. This is the same for all languages and different from how it is handled in English, where languages are always proper names.
- You have to decline adjectives, this one has to agree the noun *die Sprache* in gender, number, and case. See the adjective declination tables.
- The verb *gewöhnen* does **not** mean *to get used to* but rather *to accustom*. It's needs a person or thing as an accusative object on which the action is performed on. It cannot be *deine Zunge* in your sentence, because that item is already the accusative object to *Lass*. The conclusion is you need a reflexive pronoun to repeat *deine Zunge*.